# Is there any documentation or sample project available for android and iOS native application automation testing using webdriverio tool?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

I am using webdriverio automation tool for web application automation. And recently, I am looking forward to automation the native Android and iOS mobile application as well. When I search details on https://webdriver.io/, I do read about the availability of mobile automation support but it does not provide any details on how to configure and achieve it.
Can someone please give me relevant information that will help me automation the native applications using webdriverio tool.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the this as example https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/. I am using for my project and is working as expected.